# ClusterSharding: How to stop all the actors in a cluster shard?

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

I am working with Akka and have used ClusterSharding for a usecase. For some reason I want to stop all the actors in the ClusterShard.

Can somene help me with a way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

There's no reliable way to do this.

The closest would be to get the state of the shard (check the "Inspecting cluster sharding state" sections in the docs for [classic](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/cluster-sharding.html#inspecting-cluster-sharding-state) or [typed](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/cluster-sharding.html#inspecting-cluster-sharding-state) cluster sharding), which will contain the set of active entity IDs in each shard as of some point in time (with possibly no guarantee that the point in time is the same for all shards).  You can then use that set of entity IDs to send a message to each entity to passivate itself: each actor will need to implement that support itself (there's no equivalent of a `PoisonPill` which would work).

During all of this, there's no guarantee that more sharded entities haven't been started by cluster sharding, nor is there a guarantee that cluster sharding won't restart the entities you've stopped.